# Never withdrew ETH from The DAO

Tags: the-dao

I really need some help, at least an answer so i can put this back to rest for good, you see, when the DAO hack happened, back in 2016, I had my Dao tokens already in Poloniex and panic sold...  I owned my loss and moved on, never looking back, literally, till just yesterday, October 2-2020, I was watching a crypto documentary and my mind began bussing after it heard the words "Ethereum Rollback", I don't want to get my hopes up, even if by some miracle I could hypothetically have those Eths back, I still sold those damn Dao tokens, also I heard Mist wallet got deprecated, to many "IFs" already… Anyway, without the tokens the "rollback" is useless am I right? Or do I got the Dao tokens back to the wallet as well? Luckily I store everything, so here's the wallet from which I participated: https://etherscan.io/address/0x1110c6983efcefaac70044fb53d3b6cf9abeeb25

I just need Y/N, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As you sold your DAO tokens on Poloniex, you transferred them to someone else and you can't claim back ETH..

I see on etherscan.io that you contributed to The Dao at the beginning, so you can't claim back the "ExtraBalance" (you would have if you contributed to The Dao at a rate > 1 ETH for 100 DAO). So no you don't have anything left to recover unfortunately.